# Oracle Column type Number is showing Decimal value in spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

Using spark read jdbc option , i am reading oracle table and one of the column type is 'Number' type. After reading and writing into s3 bucket, dataframe printschema is showing decimal(38,10). I know cast to int type can help but issue with we created redshift table with Intger type and decimal value(data frame value) is not allowing to do copy command. Is there any solution other than cast option. ?

Comment: did you got the answer of this question?

Comment: No.. @NikhilAgrawal

Comment: what approach you adopted to resolve this?